# Bipartite matching with a twist

Tags: algorithm, graph, complexity-theory, graph-theory, linear-programming

I'm working on a scheduling problem assigning speakers to slots, with speakers having varying availability. A maximum matching unweighed bipartite graph works for a simple solution where each speaker is assigned to a single slot.

Now assume after every slot someone speaks in, an empty slot should follow (except the last). How can this be modelled?

Finally, can graph theory be used when some speakers should speak for consecutive slots?

Thanks

Comment: By "after each matching", do you mean that each slot someone speaks in should be followed by an empty slot? The use of the word "matching" is ambiguous.

Comment: Yes @user2357112, that's exactly what I mean. Thanks, I've reworded this.

Comment: If a speaker speaks for multiple slots, are the consecutive?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, yes consecutive slots.

Comment: IMO this is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Maybe http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: I think graph theory is a bad language to describe constraints as 'matching speakers with consecutive slots'. If you really need exact solution, try integer linear programming or dynamic programming. As the problem may be hard, consider heuristics or randomized algorithms.

Comment: @BartoszMarcinkowski I thought that would be the case, however was wondering if adding dummy variables or adding costs could model this. Can the constraint of leaving an empty slot after each matching be modelled by adjusting a graph theory algorithm?

Comment: I don't understand the problem specification. What are you trying to maximize, are there multiple speakers per time slot, when you say "an empty slow should follow", does that mean after every talk there is a pause (for the given podium), why does any arbitrary maximum matching satisfy those constraints?

Comment: @G.Bach A single speaker should be assigned to a slot and speakers are available at different times. When each talk is one slot, and there isn't a need for a pause after the talk, a solution can be computed extremely quickly as this is a maximum matching of a bipartite graph. Once you add in the constraint that a pause should be left after each talk, is it still possible to model this with graph theory? Linear/constraint programming solutions are orders of magnitude slower in comparison.

Comment: So regarding the time, would it be correct to say that you have an interval `I` (representing the duration of the conference) that is partitioned into a set `T` of intervals `I(t)` (where each `I(t)` represents a time slot where either a pause or a talk can take place)? When you say "with speakers having varying availability", do you mean that for each speaker `S`, he is only available for a subset of `T`?

Answer (score 1):

If

- every speaker who is available for an odd-numbered slot is also available for the following (even-numbered) slot, and
- there is at most one speaker who needs 2 consecutive slots, and no speakers who need 3 or more,

then a very simple algorithm works: use unweighted maximum bipartite matching, **but only allocate odd-numbered slots**, leaving every even-numbered slot empty.  If someone needs 2 consecutive slots, all that happens is that, for all pairs of slots following him/her, slot usage is swapped so that odd-numbered slots are left empty and even-numbered slots are used.